# Failure to Update Maximum Upload Limit Set By Hosting Provider and PHP Max Input Vars

Tags: php, wordpress, php.ini

Hi I deployed a VM with Wordpress only I can't update the Maximum Upload Limit Set By Hosting Provider value from 2M to 40M.

I also can't update the PHP Max Input Vars value , despite we have modified the (./etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini) php.ini and .htaccess file

Can you please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try the “Increase Maximum Upload File Size” Plug-in.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/

Another option might be to Edit the “Functions.PHP” File, using the Wordpress “Theme File Editor”.

In specific, you’ll want to Locate & Edit the following Line.

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
```

Also, be sure to Restart Apache (or whichever Web Server you’re using) after you’ve finished Updating Settings.

If you continue having issues, feel free to report back with your findings, as I may have a few other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but in case you're still having issues (or someone else happens to stumble upon this post, looking for additional information, in the future), I should note that since there's a Warning which states that "**maximum upload limit set by hosting provider**", you cannot use a Plug-in to Edit the Maximum Upload Limitation Settings.

That being said, you will need to edit the Configuration Files, directly.

**How to increase Maximum upload file size from 2MB**:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-increase-maximum-upload-file-size-from-2mb/

Comment: while this might answer the question but in fact it's offtopic due the requester has no permission to do it.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like he's done just about everything he can do (from his end, at least). And therefore the only remaining option would be to contact his hosting provider for support, per this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess